# I'm trying to make a chart with logarithmic x-axis using Recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to make a chart with logarithmic x-axis using Recharts

```
<div className="chart">
        <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={400}>
          <LineChart margin={{ top: 30, right: 30, left: 30, bottom: 30 }}>
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
            <XAxis
              dataKey={xDataKey}
              type="number"
              scale={XAxisSettings.scale}
              domain={XAxisSettings.domain}
              tick={<CustomizedAxisTick />}
              label={{ value: Xname?.value, position: 'insideBottom', offset: -15 }}
            />
            <YAxis label={{ value: Yname?.value, angle: -90, position: 'insideLeft', offset: 8, dy: 100 }} />
            {data.map((series, index) => (
              <Line key={index} data={series} dot={false} activeDot={{ stroke: 'blue', strokeWidth: 2, r: 5 }} strokeWidth={5} type="monotone" dataKey={selectedOption?.value} />
            ))}
            <Tooltip formatter={(value) => [value, Yname?.value]} separator="=" labelFormatter={(value) => [value, Xname?.value]} position={{ x: 0, y: 0 }} />
          </LineChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
      </div>
```

```
const [XAxisSettings, setXAxisSettings] = useState({ scale: 'auto', domain: [0, 1000] });
  useEffect(() => {
    setXDataKey(selectedOption2.value);
  
    const xScale = selectedOption2.value === 'Logarithmic Electric Field' ? 'log' : 'auto';
    const xDomain = selectedOption2.value === 'Logarithmic Electric Field' ? [0.1, 1000] : [0, 1000];
    setXAxisSettings({ scale: xScale, domain: xDomain });
  }, [selectedOption2, setXDataKey]);
```

Using this code, when the logarithmic option is selected, it changes the x-axis of the graph, but it is like this
[image: this is what i did]
However, I am trying to make such a graph and x-axis, how can I do it?
[image: like this]